CPU failures at low CPU frequencies
I'm running a i9-13900K, together with an RTX3090 on a ROG STRIX Z790-F GAMING WIFI mainboard. No overclocking or things like that are active.
To the problem: My CPU performs great during high-load operation, e.g. compiling heavy code or during gaming. The issue strangely occurs, when the system is in idle mode (low CPU load). I see applications crashing both under Linux and Windows with various errors. On Linux, I mostly see segfault error code 4 which points to memory or cpu issues. Anyway, two memtests I just performed did not reveal any issue with memory.
To explain this with an example: I'm running a perl script under linux which runs roughly 30 minutes with low CPU usage. It always crashed with segfault 4 after random time between immediately and couple of minutes. Now, if I run "stress -c 32" in parallel, keeping CPU freuqency high, strangely everything runs smoothly and finishes in time. I also see thunderbird, firefox, chrome crashing randomly both under Linux und Windows. Once CPU load is high, this doesn't happen anymore.
I'd like to confirm, there is an issue with my CPU. Is there any idea, how to do this?

Really interesting. Do you mean i9-13900K? Try disabling some CPUs. Try disabling some deep idle states. Try forcing your perl script to execute on only performance cores and then only on efficient cores.

Sorry for the typo. Yes, it is a i9-13900K. I'll give your suggestion a chance.
